# How to zip more than one file in one folder in shell script

Tags: shell

I am having three files one is .txt ,one is .pdf and the other is .csv . How to zip these three files in open folder and rename the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
zip file.zip file.csv file.pdf file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gzip, compress using:

> tar -czvf file.tar.gz file1 file2 file3

And extract using:

> tar -xzvf file.tar.gz